# What Really Protects File Priveleges?

Tags: security

In Windows for instance, and all operating systems, file priveleges exist that "prevent" a file from being written to if that rule is set.

This is hard to describe but please listen. People coding in a C language obviously would use some form of framework to easily modify a file. Using the built-in .Net framework, Microsoft obviously would put prevention into their classes checking file permissions before writing to a file. Since file permissions are stored via software and not hardware, what really prevents a file from being tampered with?

Let's hop over to Assembly. Suppose I create an Assembly program that directly accesses hard drive data and changes the bytes of a file. How could file permissions possibly prevent me from doing this? I guess what I am trying to ask is how a file permission really stays secure if the compiled program does not check for file permissions before writing to a file?

Comment: "Access Control" is a lower layer concept than user actions.

Comment: You can only directly access hardware from device drivers which must have the right privileges to begin with to be loaded. User-level code will have to go through OS API calls to access the file system and the OS will enforce privileges.

Comment: Okay cool. What about in the OS installation process? Obviously when the OS is being installed drivers are not set up yet nor every part of the OS. Without the API and drivers, how then is the file hierarchy created on the hard drive?

Comment: During the OS install process, the OS is in control and it actually loads basic device drivers at the beginning of installation.

Comment: "Microsoft obviously would put prevention into their classes checking file permissions before writing to a file" isn't correct. The code is inside the operating system.

Answer (score 6):

> Suppose I create an Assembly program that directly accesses hard drive data and changes the bytes of a file.  How could file permissions possibly prevent me from doing this?

If you write in assembly, your assembly is still run in a [CPU mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes) that prevents direct access to memory and devices.

> *CPU modes* … place restrictions on the type and scope of operations that can be performed by certain processes being run by the CPU. This design allows the operating system to run with more privileges than application software.

Your code still needs to issue [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to get the OS to interact with memory not owned by your process and devices.

> a *system call* is how a program requests a service from an operating system's kernel. This may include hardware related services (e.g. accessing the hard disk), creating and executing new processes, and communicating with integral kernel services (like scheduling).

The OS maintains security by monopolizing the ability to switch CPU modes and by crafting system calls so that they are *safe* for user-land code to initiate.